# how to install software via terminal?

Tags: software-installation

I want to ask how to install package in Ubuntu 14.04 using terminal 
I need a command to do that
and also a command that works with most of package to install

Answer (score 1):

You can install applications with [`apt-get`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool), Like so:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

- `sudo`

  - Ask for root(administrator) privileges for:
- `apt-get`

  - It is the tool that installs your software with the
- `install` parameter

  - The `install` parameter installs the following application:
- `firefox`

  - Mozilla Firefox, a free and open-source web-browser build to make the Internet free and accessible to anyone.

---

Other - but not all - [parameters](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-get.8.html) you can add to `apt-get`

- update

  - To update your sources list
- upgrade

  - To upgrade your applications to the newest versions
- dist-upgrade

  - upgrade your entire distribution: applications, system software etc.
- `remove`

  - To remove the selected application(e.g `sudo apt-get remove firefox`)
- `purge`

  - To not only remove the applications binaries but also it's configuration files.

**Reference**:

- [Ubuntu Manpage: apt-get - APT package handling utility -- command-line interface](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-get.8.html)
- [Advanced Packaging Tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Packaging_Tool)